# Ngnix two server block one by domain another one by IP

Tags: magento, nginx, server, php-7.1, magento2.2

I am Trying to create two instance on my NGnix server

First would be accessed by

> mydomain.com (it listening to port 80 )

Second using

> 172.32.32.123:81  (it listening to port 81 and this IP is server IP)

this is my default file

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;


    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name mydomain.com;

    location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

        location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    }


        location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
server {
    listen       81;
    server_name  172.32.32.123:81;
    root /var/www/html/root;
   index index.html index.php;
   set $MAGE_MODE developer; # or production or developer
   set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html/root/;

   location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

   }
         location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #       # With php7.0-fpm:
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    }

    include /var/www/html/root/nginx.conf.sample;
```

}
    }

The server block is working fine for the one when using domain name but in case of IP based domain only home page is working on inner pages we are getting 404 error

Comment: what does the error log show?

Comment: @TarunLalwani no error , i am greeting a 403 even ngnix -t  is showing no error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue with using following default config

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name magedev.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        index index.html index.php;
                #try_files $uri $uri/  @handler;
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
                expires 30d;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
        location ~ \.php$ {
        #include fastcgi_params;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        #fastcgi_index index.php;
            #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
        location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
    #include /var/www/html/root/nginx.conf.sample;
}
server {
       listen 81;
       server_name 192.87.123.132;

       root /var/www/html/root;
       index index.html index.php;
     set $MAGE_MODE developer; # or production or developer
     set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html/root/;
# **Inclusion of try_files Solved the  issue for me**
       location / {
               try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
               autoindex on;
               autoindex_exact_size off;

       }
             location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #       # With php7.0-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        }

    include /var/www/html/root/nginx.conf.sample;

}
```

**Inclusion of try_files Solved the  issue for me**

```
   location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
           autoindex on;
           autoindex_exact_size off;

   }
```

Comment: I'm glad that's worked for you, but as an answer on stackoverflow, it's of poor quality, as it doesn't really enlighten either other users or you yourself as to what the problem was.  Which of those configuration changes worked for you?

Comment: I have both before and after default config here , a user can easily diiff them both to see the changes

Comment: Yes, but you write it once, and then hundreds or thousands of other people read it.  Show some respect for the time it takes them to get your point.

Comment: @mc0e included explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what's supposed to happen — what is the correct path that's supposed to handle one server versus the other?!

If they're supposed to have the same underlying files, then your `root` directives are quite suspicious — one is simply `/var/www/html/`, the other one is `/var/www/html/root/` — is that intentional?

Otherwise, in case of a 404 error, the underlying path names (that aren't found) should be mentioned within the file specified by http://nginx.org/r/error_log, which will likely reveal what is up — do those returning 404 actually exist on the disc?!

Comment: It's unclear what's supposed to happen : i wanted two instance on my server one that will be accessed by IP and other using a local domain name . they are not supposed to have same files . yes they do exist . i am trying to configure a magento instance , i case of domain name all works fine but in case of when using IP only homepage works rest all the pages are 404

Answer (score 0):

1. This would be better moved to ServerFault.
2. While I'm not sure of it, The inclusion of the port in the ServerName directive looks suspicious to me.
3. This looks dangerous:

   include /var/www/html/root/nginx.conf.sample

If /var/www/html/root, and the directories above it are only writeable by root, it might be OK.  Otherwise it's likely to be a root exploit for whichever user can write to the file.  Copy the file to somewhere safe, and include it at that location.

Comment: 1. I am unfamiliar how to move it server fault , is see a lot of ngnix related issues posted here so did the same  2) I dont see any port number in ServerName it is in listen directive 3) yes it only writable by Root user